# TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

On my web page I have a google map, as well as three charts. When the page loads the map is fine, but the charts either don't load or only one or two do. Keep getting the error TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor.

```
function load() {
     //map object
        var MY_MAP = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: {lat: 54.870902, lng: -6.300565}, 
        zoom: 14
      });    
      //call to get and process data
      downloadUrl("Map.php", processXML);
  }  

 // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']}); 
        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded. 
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAltitudeChart());  
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDisplacementChart());
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDistanceChart());  



function drawAltitudeChart(){

         //console.log('hello');
         var graph = [];
          downloadUrl("Map.php", function (data){
              var xml = data.responseXML;
              var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
              var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
              var options = {title:'Altitude (m above sea level)', 
                  curveType:'function', 
                  legend:{position:'bottom'},
                  is3d:true     
              };
              var chart;

              for(var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
                  graph[i] = ['', parseInt(markers[i].getAttribute("alt"))];   
              }

              dataTable.addColumn('string', 'id');
              dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Altitude');
              dataTable.addRows(graph);


              chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
              chart.draw(dataTable, options); 

          });
      }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think you can add more than one callback like that.

Also, you can define the callback in the `load` method, like so...

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': drawCharts});

function drawCharts() {
  drawAltitudeChart();
  drawDisplacementChart();
  drawDistanceChart();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

the above `load` statement is for the **older** library...

`<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

using the **new** library...

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

changes the `load` statement to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': drawCharts});
```

---

**EDIT 2**

you can also load all the packages you need in one `load` statement, e.g.
instead of...

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['table'] });
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['pie'] });  // <-- 'pie' package does not exist
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
```

it should be...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,
  packages: ['bar', 'corechart', 'table']
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir, have a look here: https://ideone.com/53kDM8
I'm getting the same error, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work

Answer (score 13):

I got the same message, but just because I forgot to load the package

```
  // was -> google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar', 'corechart']});
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar', 'corechart', 'table']});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are using the right strategy i.e loading google charts and using callbacks on the load event, it is necessary to keep the scripts in the head tag unlike we keep the scripts at the bottom to prevent slow page load.

I am quoting this directly from documentation of google charts:

**With few exceptions, all web pages with Google Charts should include the following lines in the `<head>` of the web page:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  ...
</script>
```

Reference: [Basic Chart Loading](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#basic-library-loading)

P.S: I followed each detail but missed to keep the loading scripts in head tag, i got this error  coninuously `TypeError: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable is not a function` . Keeping the scripts in head tag resolved the issue.