# multiple Google Charts live data updating with websockets freeze the browser

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

Hope anyone can share some thoughts on this.

I was testing websockets using google charts library, the data rows is adding dynamically and synchronously from websockets.

I started with a single line chart. Everything works fine.

Then I was trying to add another chart, try rendering multiple charts in 1 page by using this https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts

Thats where the issue begun, both charts are rendering perfect at first, but after a while the browser start to freeze. Not sure if its too much memory consumed or its draw 2 charts with Websockets data is too much load for the page.

Comment: first, the reference docs are a little stale at this point -- recommend __not__ using multiple `setOnLoadCallback` statements as the link provided suggests, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32459785/5090771) for help on that -- as for _memory leaks_, it would help if you could share some code showing how data is provided to the charts...

Comment: thanks! I was doing lot research it turns out to be a known issue. I recreated another post here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874317/memory-leak-in-google-line-charts) Its a memory leak

Comment: If you have another thoughts on this can you post under that one? thanks