# Memory leak in google line charts

Tags: javascript, charts, memory-leaks, google-visualization

I have been doing lot research on this memory leak in Google charts library. Didnt found any thing thats helping my situation. Not sure whats the updates on this one so far. I saw google chart dev team is trying to fix it and release a new updates.

I'm using line chart and the data is coming from websockets. which is constantly updating.

Thanks in advance

P.S below is the code I use to getting data from websockets. when the socket is connected the drawChart function is called every second. Meaning the whole line chart is redrawn

```
function drawVisualization() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'data');
        data.addColumn('number', 'date');

        var data_test = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data_test.addColumn('string', 'data test');
        data_test.addColumn('number', 'date test');

        for(var i=0; i<valueArr.length; i+=2) {

          if (i>=120) {
            data.removeRow(0);
            valueArr.splice(0, 2);
            timeArr.splice(0, 2);
          }

          data.addRow([timeArr[i], valueArr[i]]);
        }

        for(var i=1; i<valueArr.length; i+=2) {

            if (i>=120) {
              data_test.removeRow(0);
              valueArr.splice(0, 2);
              timeArr.splice(0, 2);
            }

            data_test.addRow([timeArr[i], valueArr[i]]);
        }

        //console.log(valueArr);
        // use a DataView to 0-out all the values in the data set for the initial draw
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        var view_test = new google.visualization.DataView(data_test);

        // Create and draw the plot
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        var chart_test = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization_test'));

        var options = {
            title:" ",
            width: 960,
            height: 460,
            bar: { groupWidth: "40%" },
            legend: { position: "bottom" },
            animation: {"startup": true},
            curveType: 'function',
            lineWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
            colors: ['red'],
            tooltip: {
                textStyle: {
                  color: 'red',
                  italic: true
                },
                showColorCode: true
            },
            animation: {
                startup: true,
                easing: 'inAndOut',
                //duration: 500
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: '',
                gridlines: {
                  count: 8,
                  color: '#999'
                }
                /*minValue: 1.3,
                maxValue: 1.4*/
            },
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Time Stamp'
            },
        };

        //stay in sockets
        var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
            chart.draw(data, options);
            chart_test.draw(data, options);
        });

        chart.draw(view, options);
        chart_test.draw(view_test, options);
}

function init() {
try {
    socket = new WebSocket(portal);
    //console.log('WebSocket status '+socket.readyState);
    socket.onopen = function(msg) {
        //console.log("Welcome - status "+this.readyState);
    };


    socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        parseData(msg);
        drawVisualization();

    };

    socket.onclose = function(msg) {
        console.log("Disconnected - status "+this.readyState);
    };
}
catch(ex){
    console.log(ex);
}
}
```

Comment: depending on the amount of data and options set, the chart could possibly take more than one second to draw -- recommend waiting until the first draw finishes, before attempting to draw again -- to know when the chart is finished drawing, listen for the `'ready'` event, or `'animationfinish'` if using animation -- there maybe other issues within `drawVisualization` -- you should be creating the chart only once, then re-drawing with new data using the same chart instance...

Comment: Please check the code I just attached above. So you are suggesting I can separate the draw() function into data.addRow() and when socket connected call data.addRow() periodically.

Comment: I was trying on this solution earlier. But I'm having some trouble "separating the code" do I declare all variables inside my drawVisualization() function global? or?

Comment: In the code above I was trying to splice/pop out the data in the array, but seems like thats wont do anything. The objects from older charts has been stored in the DOM.

Comment: I'm thinking of bind() the functions. currying? I'm kinda new to javascript :)

Comment: yes, valueArr and time Arr are all parsed data arrays from parseData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beginning with drawing only one chart, you might setup similar to following snippet...

this *should* draw the same chart with new data, only after the previous draw has finished...

```
function init() {
  var getData = true;

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    getData = true;
  });

  var options = {
    title:" ",
    width: 960,
    height: 460,
    bar: { groupWidth: "40%" },
    legend: { position: "bottom" },
    animation: {"startup": true},
    curveType: 'function',
    lineWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
    colors: ['red'],
    tooltip: {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'red',
        italic: true
      },
      showColorCode: true
    },
    animation: {
      startup: true,
      easing: 'inAndOut',
      //duration: 500
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: '',
      gridlines: {
        count: 8,
        color: '#999'
      }
      /*minValue: 1.3,
      maxValue: 1.4*/
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time Stamp'
    },
  };

  // if you want data from previous draws, declare here...
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  // or see below...

  // msg = object with arrays from parseData
  function drawVisualization(msg) {

    // if you ** don't ** want data from previous draws, declare here instead...
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    // ---<

    for (var i = 0; i < msg.valueArr.length; i++) {
      data.addRow([msg.timeArr[i], msg.valueArr[i]]);
    }

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  function parseData(msg) {
    //... declare timeArr & valueArr locally here

    return {
      timeArr: timeArr,
      valueArr: valueArr
    };
  }

  function startData() {
    try {
      socket = new WebSocket(portal);
      //console.log('WebSocket status '+socket.readyState);

      socket.onopen = function(msg) {
        //console.log("Welcome - status "+this.readyState);
      };

      socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        if (getData) {
          getData = false;

          // pass object with arrays from parseData
          drawVisualization(parseData(msg));
        }
      };

      socket.onclose = function(msg) {
        //console.log("Disconnected - status "+this.readyState);
      };
    }
    catch(ex){
      console.log(ex);
    }
  }
  startData();
}
```

Comment: starting with only one chart, recommend similar setup as above -- how do multiple charts come into play? and do you want to keep data from previous calls? if so, you may want to set some sort of max on the number of rows...

Comment: do you noticed the 2 loops I had in my code. looping inside the same array. Cause I'm drawing 2 charts with data coming from the same websocket

Comment: Yeah i do have a i>120 setted up when after 120 seconds or close. the array will pop out the 1 element every second.

Comment: looks like both charts use the same data??

Comment: Yes, btw I'm trying out the solution you suggested. It works towards the same result as I had before. I dont understand how this will avoid memory leak?

Comment: Its still calling the whole drawChart function in socket.onmessage that means another new chart is drawing every time when theres data. The memory consumption is still accumulating